# Unable to access volunteer functionality

Tags: civivolunteer

With Drupal 7.64 CiviCRM version 5.10.4 & civivolunteer version 4.7.31-2.3.1 
Created a new event. Under the Volunteer tab in event configuration, there are three buttons Log Volunteer Hours button is working and other two buttons Define Volunteer Opportunities, Assign Volunteers not working after clicking on those buttons nothing happens.
Anyone facing the same issues?

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why this may fail, You can use troubleshoot method below to find cause of the problem.

1. Make sure you don't have any JS error on browser console.
2. Check if you have set extension url in Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URL
3. Clear template_c by running cleanup caches(Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths)

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep
Have already set extension Url path properly under Resource URL & tried clearing cache but still it not working. Regarding JS error have checked under console it shows js error like `Uncaught TypeError: CRM.volunteerPopup is not a function`.

Comment: This suggests to me that not all of the appropriate JS assets are being loaded. I would recommend quadruple-checking all of your path and directory settings. Also verify that other AngularJS-based pages such as /civicrm/a/#/status and /civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/manage behave correctly.

Comment: @universalhandle As per your suggestion,  I have checked both Angular JS-based pages those are working properly. Also, extension URL path & directory settings are configured properly, Still, it shows the error as I mentioned in an earlier comment. It's strange that one button is working as expected and other two (Define Volunteer Opportunities, Assign Volunteers) are having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that strange; those buttons are wired up differently. It could be a bug -- CiviVolunteer has not had a proper release in 10 months and may be out of sync with CiviCRM core. On the other hand, if memory serves, those modals are powered by Backbone.Marionette, so the problem may actually be that the appropriate JavaScript isn't being loaded in that context.